# TO_TIMESTAMP Compare

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-timestamp

```
SELECT  lastmoddate
        , to_timestamp(lastmoddate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS:FF AM')
        , cast(current_timestamp - interval '60' day as TIMESTAMP)
FROM table 
WHERE primaryKeyColumn = 12141969;
```

returns:

[image]

```
SELECT problemid
       , lastmoddate
       , to_timestamp(lastmoddate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS:FF AM')
       , cast((current_timestamp - 60) as TIMESTAMP)
FROM table 
WHERE primaryKeyColumn = 12141969
and to_timestamp(lastmoddate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS:FF AM') < cast((current_timestamp - 60)  as TIMESTAMP);
```

returns:

[image]

I don't understand how is 25th Aug less than 19th Aug.

Comment: The date `25-AUG-18` is ambiguous, because it lacks the century.  Perhaps it is very, very old.

Comment: The lastmoddate (presumably a string) starts with 25-AUG-18 and you are specifying a YYYY format mask so it has gone with 0018.

Comment: Here's hopefully another nail in the coffin of "don't store dates as strings". If this doesn't convince you to change how you store dates (no excuse; oracle has had date/time stamp type columns for at least 20 years now) to something proper, I'm not sure what will!

Comment: Why are you storing timestamps as strings. You should **never** do that.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, Especially Gordon, Gary. You guys nailed it. When I ran did to_CHAR(lastmoddate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') I noticed it had 0018 stored in Year. This solved my problem.

lastmoddate is Timestamp in database Since I had trouble getting the correct answer I tried converting it to to_timestamp. May be this made readers think as if lastmoddate is String in database.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, Especially Gordon, Gary. You guys nailed it. When I ran to_CHAR(lastmoddate,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI') I noticed it had 0018 stored in Year. This solved my problem